# How to fix "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error in Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I have decided to make some code that encodes messages based on a shuffled string, including all of the ASCII letters. Here is the code:

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters
from random import shuffle

Code = list(letters)

shuffle(Code)

''.join(Code)

print("Your code is:")
for i in Code:
    print(i, end="")

print(" ")
message = input("Input your message: ")

for i in message:
    if message[i] == 'a':
        message[i] = Code[0]
...
```

So I expected it to work but for some reason, I just got "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: `message` is string, so `i` is char (not index), so you have ie. `message["A"]`. You need `if i == "a"` and you could use list for results - `result.append(code[0])` or use `for i, char in enumarate(message):` to get char and index.

Comment: maybe create dictionary `{"a": "z", "b":"q", ...}` and use it instead all `if`. It wil be shorter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `''.join(Code)` but it isnt assigned to anything so Code is still a list. To make it to string do `Code = ''.join(Code)`.

```
for i in Code:
    print(i, end="")
print(" ")
```

is same as `print(Code)` after converting it to string.
You are iterating over message so i is character but you are treating it as index:

You could also do this: Note ord converts it to ascii value

```
for i in range(len(message)):
    if message[i] == 'a':
        message = message.replace(message[i], Code[0])
```

You can convert it to ascii to handle other characters

```
    message = message.replace(message[i], Code[ord(message[i])- ord('a')])
```

`ord(message[i])- ord('a')` gets appropriate index for Code.
or

```
for c in message:
    message = message.replace(c, Code[ord(c)- ord('a')])
```